# Dynamically creating child and parent class inhertance

Tags: c++, inheritance, radix

Why is is this not allowed Rectangle *test = new Shape();

But you can Shape *testRect = new Rectangle();

I would of assumed the first to be allowed as the child inherits the base, so you can create a Shape from a Rectangle.  And Shape cannot dynamically create Rectangle as it does not know anything about classes that inherit it.

```
// Base class
    class Shape {
       public:
          void setWidth(int w) {
             width = w;
          }
          void setHeight(int h) {
             height = h;
          }
        int getShape() { 
             return (width *1000); 
          }
       protected:
          int width;
          int height;
    };
    // Derived class
    class Rectangle: public Shape {
       public:
          int getArea() { 
             return (width * height); 
          }
    };
    int main(void) {
        // not does not work
       //Rectangle *test = new Shape();
        // allowed
       Shape *testRect = new Rectangle();
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should read about polymorphism and how `virtual` function and destructors works too.

Answer (score 2):

```
Shape *testRect = new Rectangle();
```

is allowed because every `Rectangle` *is* a `Shape`.

```
Rectangle *test = new Shape();
```

can't work because a `Shape` *is not* a `Rectangle`.

---

Your following argumentation is absolutely correct.

> I would of assumed the first to be allowed as the child inherits the base, so you can create a Shape from a Rectangle. And Shape cannot dynamically create Rectangle as it does not know anything about classes that inherit it.

You probably just confused what is what. Basically any pointer that points to a `Rectangle` (like the one returned from `new Rectangle()`) also points to a `Shape`, so the first assigment is valid.

But the pointer returned from `new Shape()`) does not point to any `Rectangle`, so the second assingment is invalid.

Comment: That code is not going to work anyway because of object slicing and missing virtual function

Answer (score 0):

You should learn more about inheritance in C++.

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/basic-inheritance-in-c/

base class pointers can point to derived class objects but not the other way round.